# What service could be adding NewRelic?

Tags: javascript, analytics, tracking, tools

At the bottom of my web pages is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> if (!NREUMQ.f) {NREUMQ.f=function() {NREUMQ.push(["load",new Date().getTime()]);var e=document.createElement("script"); e.type="text/javascript"; e.src=(("http:"===document.location.protocol)?"http:":"https:") + "//" + "js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-100.js"; document.body.appendChild(e);if(NREUMQ.a)NREUMQ.a();};NREUMQ.a=window.onload;window.onload=NREUMQ.f;};NREUMQ.push(["nrfj","beacon-2.newrelic.com","e4797ae5b8","2247360","blwGYUsADBADAEIIVlcWJWZpTgYGBAJDDU0XWBdFQQ==",0,15,new Date().getTime(),"4CA2163B5F6C6DE7","","","",""]);</script>
```

What I'd like to know is, what put it there? I don't have any direct connection with NewRelic, so my guess is that one of my third party tools has placed it there. It's across all pages but a lot of my third party tools are on my master page so are inherited by all pages.

A quick list of what I can remember using on the site:

- Google Tag Manager to add:

  - Google Analytics
  - Google Adwords
  - Bing Analytics
  - Marketo Munchkin
- LivePerson.com
- jQuery and jQuery UI (Google CDN hosted)
- Google Fonts

Same problem in Chrome, Chrome Incognito and FF, so it's not a browser plugin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure NewRelic isn't installed on the server?

Comment: Yep, Tim is right. It's normally an extension which runs in the background that will inject that server side script.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it meant I knew who to go and speak to. It turns this was installed by our internal systems team when investigating server performance or something. Seems an incredibly invasive technique, it puts the script on every site! Anyway, mystery solved, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NewRelic is a service side process monitor that logs various system resources among many other things, it attaches itself to various server programs and monitors them. So in other words its a process running in the background along side your server setup.

If your using shared hosting then its doubtful that you can do anything about this other than change host because I wouldn't want them looking at my visitor information in depth.

But I'd assume you have your own dedicated server or vps service then you can follow their remove information:

> ***[SOURCE](https://newrelic.com/docs/site/uninstalling-the-agent)***
>
> PHP
>
> To remove the PHP agent and leave the configuration file intact (in
>   case you want to reinstall the agent), execute the newrelic-install
>   script (as root):
>
> `sudo /usr/bin/newrelic-install`
>
> To fully remove the agent, include the purge option. This will remove
>   everything from your system:
>
> `sudo /usr/bin/newrelic-install purge`
>
> For more information, see The newrelic-install Script and PHP agent
>   installation documents. Python
>
> To uninstall your Python agent, use one of these methods:
>
> ```
> If installed with PIP: `pip uninstall newrelic/.`
> If installed with easy_install: `easy_install -m newrelic.`
> ```
>
> For more information about installation, see New Relic for Python.
>   Ruby
>
> To remove the Ruby agent from your Rails application, remove the
>   newrelic.yml file from within your RAILS_ROOT/config/ file.
>
> To remove New Relic from your Gemfile, delete this line:
>
> `gem 'newrelic_rpm'`
>
> Then run:
>
> `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

Developer Evangelist at Marketo here. I can confirm that it's not the Marketo Munchkin tracking code that is loading New Relic.